# why dose Request.Form["key"] not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.write

I am trying to make c# ASP.net code that when I press on the submit form button it will show a table with the form's answers.
My only problem is when I'm pressing the submit button nothing happens... 
can you please tell me where is my problem?
Here is my C# code:

```
public string st = " ";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (Request.Form["submit"] != null)
      {
        st += "<table dir = 'ltr' align = 'center' border = '1'>";
        st += "<tr><th colspan = '2' align = 'center'> form results </th> 
               </tr>";
        string uName = Request.Form["uName"];
        string Pass = Request.Form["Pass"];
        string eMail = Request.Form["eMail"];
        st += "<tr><td> User Name: </td><td>" + uName + "</td></tr>";
        st += "<tr><td> Password </td><td>" + Pass + "</td></tr>";
        st += "<tr><td> eMail </td><td>" + eMail + "</td></tr>";
        st += "</table>";
       }
    }
```

And here is the line from .aspx code:

```
</table>
<% Response.Write(st); %>
```

this is the top of the aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="master.master" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="mainMasterPage.Register" %>
```

Thanks! 
Tal

*FIXED*

instead of type `Request.Form["..."]`
I type `Request["..."]`
and thats it!
Thank you all

Comment: I made some edits in my post and put the line from the aspx where I'm using the Response.Write();

Comment: change this `if (Request.Form["submit"] != null)` to `if(IsPostBack)` and try again

Comment: Tip: Use StringBuilder instead of string for building up strings like this.

Comment: still nothing...

Comment: maybe the table is there, but you not see it - check the page source

Comment: of course you must NOT have place it inside `UpdatePanel`

Comment: @Aristos I'm sorry, but what is the meaning of UpdatePanel?

Comment: What is `Request.Form["submit"]`? Do you have an input element named `submit` ?

Comment: @Crowcoder sure

Comment: check also on the aspx page on the top that have `AutoEventWireup="true"`

Comment: @Aristos the AutoEventWireup is true

Comment: You say "nothing happens" but I doubt that is true. Open your browser developer tools and make sure the network trace is on. Then do your thing and look at what your request and response (if any) are. Look for console errors too.

Comment: @Crowcoder I have checked what you are saying, the only change i could see that the form content disappear when i'm pressing the submit button. Beside that nothing happens.